# Merge YAML into specific array entry with yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Given master.yml ...

```yaml
containers:
  - name: project-a
    items:
      - CCC
  - name: project-z
    items:
      - CCC
      - DDD
```

... and an update.yml ...

```yaml
- name: project-z
  items:
    - CCC
    - EEE
```

... I want to merge it into the correct entry. This would give:

```yaml
containers:
  - name: project-a
    items:
      - CCC
  - name: project-z
    items:
      - CCC
      - DDD
      - EEE
```

The following yq 4 works *if the update was for `project-a`*

```
yq ea 'select(fileIndex==0) * {"containers":select(fileIndex==1)}' master.yml update.yml
```

but, with the provided `project-z` update, it incorrectly replaces the first array entry (you end up with two `project-z`s).

Comment: @Inian Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out though I don't know if my WIP is actually helpful here or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deep-dive into the manuals, I have this :

```
yq ea 'select(fi==1).0.name as $p | (select(fi==0).containers.[] | select(.name==$p)) = (select(fi==1) | .0 | . headComment="AUTO-UPDATED") |  select(fi==0)'  master.yml update.yml
```

which replaces rather than merges `project-z` by first searching `name` matching `update.yml` then completely replacing the content.

I understand the root cause being data is formatted as a *list* where it should be a *dictionary* (`name` is unique).

This would merge trivially and be better in future too!

```yaml
containers:
  project-a:
    items:
      - CCC
  project-z:
    items:
      - CCC
      - DDD
      - EEE
```

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to another stackoverflow question in which kev had a really neat solution for (I think).

I've since added his solution to yq docs here: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-arrays-of-objects-together-matching-on-a-key

In your case, this will only work if the second file matched the structure of the first, (that is, it also has 'containers' as a parent):

```sh
yq eval-all '
(
  ((.containers[] | {.name: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . *+ $item )) as $uniqueMap
  | ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
) as $mergedArray
| select(fi == 0) | .containers  = $mergedArray
` file.yaml file2.yaml
```

```
containers:
  - name: project-a
    items:
      - CCC
  - name: project-z
    items:
      - CCC
      - DDD
      - CCC
      - EEE
```

Basically it works by reducing into a merged map based on name (as you mention this would be much easier if that was already the case) and then converting that back to an array.

Disclaimer: I wrote yq