# yq, transform and merge two arrays

Tags: yaml, yq

I have two files from which I want to merge two arrays, one of which I have to transform first.

I already had a look at [yq's documentation](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-arrays-of-objects-together-matching-on-a-key) and multiple SO posts, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66153291/merge-yaml-into-specific-array-entry-with-yq).
But unfortunately I get `null` but have the feeling I'm close but I'm not sure what I'm missing

**File 1**

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind,x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 1234
        hostPort: 31234
```

**File 2**

```
traefik:
 metadata:
   namespace: dev
 ports:
   metrics:
     nodePort: 32555
   web:
     nodePort: 30000
```

***desired output***

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind,x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 1234
        hostPort: 31234
      - hostPort:  32555
      - hostPort: 30000
```

Here's my current implementation with `yq v4.40.5`

`.test = ((select(fi == 0) | .nodes[0].extraPortMappings) *d (((((select(fi == 1) | .traefik.ports[] | {.nodePort: .}) as $item ireduce({}; . * $item)) as $uniqueMap | ($uniqueMap | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + {"hostPort": $item.value.nodePort))) | del(.. | select(tag == "!!seq" and length == 0)))) | select(fi == 0)' ./file1.yaml ./file2.yaml`

I currently just assign to `.test` just to see if I get back anything, but it's always `null` and I don't get why.
When try to assign to `file2` (i.e. changing the last select to `select(fi == 1)` it assigns it as expected)

I think I'm missunderstanding something about yq because the following rather simple assignment isn't working either

`.test = ((select(fi == 0) | .nodes[0].extraPortMappings)) | select(fi == 1)' ./file1.yaml ./file2.yaml`

*How can I write my merged array to `file1.yaml`?*

Comment: just an addendum. I did missunderstand something about yq ;)
Thought the default command was `eval-all` but it is `eval` that's why I didn't get any results at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, all you want is to turn each value in `.traefik.ports[].nodePort` from the second file into an object with field `hostPort`, and add that to the array under `.nodes[0].extraPortMappings` in the first file:

```bash
yq '.nodes[0].extraPortMappings += [
  {"hostPort": load("file2.yaml").traefik.ports[].nodePort}
]' file1.yaml
```

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind,x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 1234
        hostPort: 31234
      - hostPort: 32555
      - hostPort: 30000
```

Note: Use the `-i` flag to write the results back into  `file1.yaml`.

Tested [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.35.1